# How do I refer a different screen in LightSwitch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I need to get a value of a text box which is the parent screen in the ListDetails screen.

The parent screen gives me a list of users and the child (details) screen gives me a list of permissions associated with that user. When I add a new permission, I need the userId field (in the add new screen) to have the userId of the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of referring to the parent screen add a parameter to the child screen. As you navigate from the parent screen to the child screen LightSwitch requires the parameter (e.g. userId) to show the screen. The value is then available on the child screen.

In the link below 'stateName' is passed to the child screen and used to run a query

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dbd951/8044/